# Prolog, produce lists with m first members reversed

Tags: recursion, prolog, predicate

I have a trouble finding a solution to the following problem in Prolog.

Say we have a list with N+1 members (i.e. [X1, X2, X3, ..., XN, X(N+1)]). We want to write a predicate (with recursion) in prolog that produces all possible lists which have reversed the first m of their members, with m taking values 2<=m<=N. For example if we have the list [1,2,3,4,5,6], then the predicate should return the lists:
[2,1,3,4,5,6], [3,2,1,4,5,6], [4,3,2,1,5,6], [5,4,3,2,1,6].
The predicate **must** have the form

```
move(List1, List2):-
```

Where List1 is the original list and List2 is the resulted list after the reversal of m first members.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can obtain the desired result by combining predicates ```append(P,S,L)``` (to break list ```L``` into a prefix ```P``` and a suffix ```S```) and ```reverse(P,R)``` (to transform list ```P``` into the corresponding reversed list ```R```).

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be more difficult than

```
reverse_n(Xs,N,Ys) :-   % reverse the first N of Xs to form Ys:
    length(Pfx,N),      %   - construct a list of unbound vars of length N
    append(Pfx,Sfx,Xs), %   - partition the source list into a Pfx and Sfx
    reverse(Pfx,Rev),   %   - reverse the prefix
    append(Rev,Sfx,Ys). %   - Finally, glue it back together
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. The proposed solution somehow is close to what I'm looking for but not exactly.
Actually I need the reversing procedure to start from the second member of the list (cause there's no point of reversing an empty list or the first element of the list since it returns the same list) and to terminate right after the (n-1)th member.